# Comparing Columns - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to make a simple Macro in excel by Comparing two column. 
For example.

```
A        B              C
---------------------------
john     1              5
tom      2              2
henry    3              7
Mike     4              4
```

So in this case, I compare 1,5 , 2,2 , 3,7 and 4,4. 
Later I will sending rows that are the same via an email.
This is my code for sending email..

```
Sub sendEmail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outllok.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    olMail.To = "myemail@example.com"
    olMail.Subject = "Testing"
    olMail.Body = "THis is the body"
    olMail.Send


End Sub
```

Now I just want to compare the two columns and store the "name/s" somewhere and send them in the body of the email..

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do something similar:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim name As String

'Loop over your rows
For i = 0 to 100

If Worksheets("YourSheet").Cells(i,2).Value = Worksheets("YourSheet").Cells(i,3).Value Then

'Now get the name value
name = Worksheets("YourSheet").Cells(i,1).Value

'Now do what you want with your name

End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster method using Arrays. If you have large amount of rows then looping through rows will be very slow.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim olApp As Object, olMail As Object
    Dim MyData
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")

    '~~> Store the range in the array
    '~~> I have taken 1000 rows. Change as applicable
    MyData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1000")

    For i = LBound(MyData) To UBound(MyData) - 1
        If MyData(i, 2) = MyData(i, 3) Then
            Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

            '~~> This will give you the names
            Debug.Print MyData(i, 1)

            With olMail
                .To = "myemail@example.com"
                .Subject = "Testing"
                .Body = MyData(i, 1)
                .Display '.Send
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer man. I get an error "Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)' Automation error Invalid Syntax"..
why I try to debug, it moves to this line..
"   Set olApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")"

Comment: Try using `CreateObject` (the one that is in your own code) instead of `GetObject`

Comment: @Sam092: It is not necessary.  :) Outlook is the only MS-Office application where it is not important whether you use `GetObject` or `CreateObject`. And the reason is very simple, `Createobject`doesn't create a new instance is there is already an instance opened.

Comment: I understand if you have an open instance, you should be able to use `GetObject`. But the fact is I have Outlook already opened, and `GetObject` does return an error just like OP

Comment: Did some search on the internet, apparently it should be 

`GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`

Comment: @sam: yes, I missed the ",". Good Catch. Updated the post

Comment: @SiddharthRout I didn't notice the range. Hundreds of new emails pop up when I run your code lol

Comment: @Sam092: And hence the comment `'~~> I have taken 1000 rows. Change as applicable` :p